# cors not working for my spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors, spring-mvc-test

Here is my webConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

I have a `/health` endpoint, which returns some health data and it works fine.

Here is junit test

```
@Test
    public void corsTest() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, "http://localhost:9000");
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Status> entity = this.restTemplate.exchange("/health", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Status.class);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, entity.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals("http://localhost:9000", entity.getHeaders().getAccessControlAllowOrigin()); //6
        Status health = entity.getBody();
        assertThat(health.getAppName()).isEqualTo(appName);
    }
```

Test fails at line 6. if comment-out that line, the test passes.
Through debugger, I found that `entity.getHeaders().getAccessControlAllowOrigin()` is null. I used this [sample app](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service-cors/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/GreetingIntegrationTests.java) as reference and it works fine. but for my application it fails.

when I use javascript to call the /health api, I can see the cors works. If I comment out, webConfig class, I get error in javascript. Debugging more at javascript shows that cors response header is not set but the request served successfully when webconfig is enabled.

so definitely cors works. It is the test that is failing. so I am guessing test is not seeing it for reasons I don't know.

Comment: CORS only applies to AJAX requests, so it's odd to write a test that simulates a JAVA client.

Comment: @zeroflagL: I felt the same. but the link I gave above, has test written in java. so I was trying to emulate it

Answer (score 14):

I think you need to add cors origin filter , I am not sure but I think this below solution is works for you.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        if(request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())){
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());
        }else{
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243065/springboot-how-to-set-order-of-filter-without-annotation/38464070#38464070) it is required to set the corsfilter  to be loaded before  **errorPageFilter** from spring boot. Otherwise CORS support will be broken and the required headers won't be introduced. This can be accomplished with the `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` as indicated above.

Comment: I am not using filter

Comment: Your solution works fine for me. However, I do not figure out why. I think this is a bug or drawback for CorsFilter.

Comment: Not sure I understand... it is just the Order annotation that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you didn't use the annotation driven cors config, but the java config one.

In this case I spot a difference in the example you posted and the example from github.

The latter one uses

```
registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
```

whereas your example misses the allowedOrigins

```
registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig");
```

I thinks that this makes the difference here.

Comment: I am allowing origin *. thats why it is missing it